# jQuery's "$.when().done()" for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I was looking for some way to know when two or more ajax calls have finished using AngularJS but I was only able to find it using jQuery:

```
$.when(promise3, promise5).done(
    function(threeSquare, fiveSquare) {
        console.info(threeSquare, fiveSquare);
    }
);
```

and:

```
var promises = [
    $.getJSON('square/2'),
    $.getJSON('square/3'),
    $.getJSON('square/4'),
    $.getJSON('square/5')
];

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
    console.info(arguments);
});
```

is there any way to do something like this using AngularJS?
Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will want to look at $q.all(); You can read about it [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q#Methods).

Here is a snippet:

> **all (promises)**
>
> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when
>   all of the input promises are resolved.
>
> Parameters promises – {Array.} – An array of promises.
>   Returns {Promise} – Returns a single promise that will be resolved
>   with an array of values, each value corresponding to the promise at
>   the same index in the promises array. If any of the promises is
>   resolved with a rejection, this resulting promise will be resolved
>   with the same rejection.

In version 1.1.x, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$q.all([
    $http.get('square/2'),
    $http.get('square/3'),
    $http.get('square/4'),
    $http.get('square/5')
]).then( function(arrayOfResponses) {
    $log.info('all set');
    $log.debug(arrayOfResponses);
});
```

**Update:**

As of version 1.1.6, you should be able to do the following:

```
var Square = $resource('square/:id', {id:1});
$q.all([
    Square.get({id:2}).$promise,
    Square.get({id:3}).$promise,
    Square.get({id:4}).$promise,
    Square.get({id:5}).$promise
]).then(function(arrayOfResponses) {
    $log.info('all set');
    $log.debug(arrayOfResponses);
});
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear on whether $resource.get returns a promise, even in 1.1.x versions of angular.. reading the code it looks like you might have to do "Square.get({squareId:2}).$q".  Or you could just use $http.get.

Comment: @Karl Zilles, I believe you are correct but the documentation seems a bit fuzzy when it comes to the changes made to $resource. It looks like $http.get returns a promise. I'll update my example. Thanks.

Comment: It looks as though $resource has $then but does not give you access to the promise. However, it does look like the $promise feature is coming in 1.1.6: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/05772e15fbecfdc63d4977e2e8839d8b95d6a92d